# insert into Select Sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Please answer me if you know how to insert values into columns added into an existing table. Your answer will be highly appreciated

```
insert into table a
(name, id)
select col
from table2
;

select col from table2;
```

this sql col data is 'john','1'
this is impassible ?

Comment: Do you mean col has the value `'john','1'`, as two strings separated by a comma?

Comment: table2 col data is 'john', '1' . i want write to the sql right that. only use 'col'

Comment: You shouldn't store data like that... Comma separated data is a pain in SQL.

Comment: Is the `col` data literally `'John','1'`, _with_ those single quotes?

Comment: yes has single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using the base string functions here:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE a (name, id)
SELECT
    SUBSTR(col, 1, INSTR(col, ',') - 1),
    SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, ',') + 1)
FROM table2;
```

If you don't want to insert the insert quotes, then we can slightly modify the above to the following:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE a (name, id)
SELECT
    SUBSTR(col, 2, INSTR(col, ',') - 2),
    SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, ',') + 2, LEN(col) - INSTR(col, ',') - 2)
FROM table2;
```

As has been mentioned in the above comments, storing CSV data in your tables is generally not a good idea.  But your question is a good one, because you are trying to solve that problem by moving each value to a new column.